# Convert list to multidimensional list

Tags: python

I have a list containing 100 items. How do I convert it to a 20*5 two-dimensional list? My code:

```
l = [2,3,1,...,77]
m = 20
n = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of nested loops should do the trick:

```
result = []
for i in range(m):
    row = []
    for j in range(n):
        row.append(l[i * n + j])

    result.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]
n = 5
```

**Using list comprehension**

```
subLists = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

**Using a generator**

```
def make_sublists_generator(l, sublists_size):
    for i in range(0, len(l), sublists_size):
        yield l[i : i + sublists_size]

subLists = list(make_sublists_generator(l, n))
```

**Both output the same**

```
print(str(subLists))

[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

**Note**

It still works if the list does not have a size multiple of n, the last sublist will simply be shorter. You might want to check `len(l)%sublists_size` at the start of the `make_sublists` function if you want to raise an Exception